# when to store config data in .plist?

Tags: macos, cocoa, plist, configuration-files

I am working on Mac application,in which i have to store configuration information like current version of an application etc.
I have go through some tutorials like [this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpruntimeconfig/Articles/UserPreferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002092-BCIJBCCF)

And I came to know that information is store in Preferences like com.apple.textedit.plist in ~/Library/Preferences.

But my question is when to store this basic information in .plist. ?!

Comment: Not quite sure what your are asking, do you want to know how to store it in plist, or when use plist over other methods?

Comment: @xfx  Ok.as far as my knowledge is concern Configuration info is store in Registry for windows,and information in Registry is store while Application is Install in your System.
So,my question is when to store this information in plist ?!

Comment: when you run that app. The system will check if the preference file exists, if not, create it. So, your app's preference file will exists "anytime", coz when you open it, the preferences exists.

Comment: ok..so,i have to create ~Library/Preferences/com.apple.applicationname/plistname.plist and create key value pair.while my application run it will fetch values from .plist..right ?!

Comment: no, the system do it for you. you just need NSUserDefaults. check it's documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register user defaults (the default values for preferences) when your app starts up, for example, in the + (void)initialize method in your app delegate like this:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary
                             dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:someObject, @"key",
                             nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

When the user makes changes to the default values, those changes will be automatically saved to your app's .plist file in the Preferences folder.  There should be no need to ever read or write directly to the preferences file.
Check out the [preferences programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html).